# Sum if frequency countif unique cells

Tags: excel, unique, frequency, countif

We get calls in our system, people press menu keys on their phone.

We don't want to count duplicate calls. This formula works.

We want the formula to ignore calls that were less than 60 seconds.

I only want the function to run when the row in column C is <60.

This is my function:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(($B$1:$B$94={"1,1"}),COUNTIF($A$1:$A$94,"<"&$A$1:$A$94),""),COUNTIF($A$1:$A$94,"<"&$A$1:$A$94))>0))
```

With the data as such:

```
       A           B      C
(888) 208-0980    1,1    479
(888) 208-0980    1,1    479
(888) 208-0980    1,1    60
(888) 208-0980    1,2    50
(888) 540-7272    1,4    10
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

This is an array so when you copy it in you will need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The function only counts one instance of the number given the constraint. I want to add another constraint that is if C is greater than 60.

Comment: How'd you come up with the original formula? What have you tried to change so that it performs the other task? Where did that go wrong?

Comment: I ape up with the formula by trial and error and reading forums. Everything works correctly except the condition where I only want it to run if time in column C is over 60

Comment: @calebcjb But what have you tried to add to the formula for that conditional?  Have you tried another IF statement?

Comment: Yes I have, I can't get it to work. I don't know why.

Comment: @calebcjb Alright, can you please show us _what_ you have tried?  I don't know why either because I don't know what you tried...

Comment: If you could tell what data you have in columns and what you want to achieve, we could probably find out easier ways of doing it. That formula is a monster :p

Comment: Here is a screenshot.
http://imgur.com/ykuGtBE

Comment: I added an explanation. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

OK, its a hell of a formula and does take some deconstructing.

The `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$94,"<"&$A$1:A$94)` phrase generates an array of length 94 equal to `{0,1,2,...,93}` **except** where the corresponding phone number in `$A$1:$A$94` duplicates an earlier number (when reading down column A), the corresponding array value of the first occurrence of the number is used. So, for example, the number "(888) 941-1960" occurs three times in rows 11, 12 and 13 of column A. The eleventh array element corresponds to the first occurrence of this number (in A11) and its value is 10. This value is repeated in the twelfth and thirteenth elements of the array, reflecting the duplicate values in A12 and A13. The number of distinct values in the array matches to the number of distinct phone numbers in `$A$1:$A$94` I'll use `PhoneIndex` as a shorthand for this array.

The `IF` part re-written is `IF($B1:$B94={"1,1"},PhoneIndex,"")`. This is an array of length 94 which simply replaces elements of `PhoneIndex` with zero-length strings where the corresponding entry in column B is not `"1,1"`. I'll use `PhoneIndex2` as a shorthand for this second array.

The `FREQUENCY` part rewritten is `FREQUENCY(PhoneIndex2, PhoneIndex)`. An undocumented feature of the FREQUENCY function is that if values are duplicated in the second argument (the so-called *Bins_array*) then the duplicates are ignored and corresponding frequency values in the Bins_array are set as zero. `PhoneIndex` corresponds to all the phone numbers in `$A$1:$A$94` (with duplicates), so the function delivers a third array (again of length 94) whose elements correspond in order to the  phone numbers in `$A$1:$A$94` and which provide a frequency count of the number of calls made from that number where 1,1 was pressed **but** any elements in the array corresponding to a duplicated phone number have a value of zero. I'll call this array `CallCount`.

The rest of the formula boils down to `{=SUM(--(CallCount>0))}`. The boolean comparison converts the array of frequency values in `CallCount` to an array containing `True` and `False` values according to whether or not any calls from the corresponding phone number in `$A$1:$A$94` were associated associated with a `"1,1"` in column B. The double negative converts the array of booleans into an array of 1's and 0's which can then be summed. It is the boolean comparison and the double negative which ensures that a frequency count greater than 1 gets converted to a value of 1 for use in the summation. This is the mechanism which excludes duplicate calls in the final result.

Having deconstructed the formula, I'll now turn to modifying it to exclude calls less than 60 seconds. The obvious starting point is that `IF`part. My intial thought was to modify its first argument and make it something like

`AND($B$1:$B$94={"1,1"}, $C$1:$C$94>=60)`

but, though valid syntactically, it delivers an array whose elements are either all `True` or all `False` - with the latter being by far the most likely outcome. I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to figure out why both these observations hold.

Of course, what is really required is to combine the two arrays of booleans (`$B$1:$B$94={"1,1"}` and  `$C$1:$C$94>=60`) to yield an array of length 94 where each element is the equivalent of an AND operation being performed on the two corresponding elements from each input array.

One solution is

`1=((1*($B$1:$B$94={"1,1"}))*(1*($C$1:$C$94>=60)))`

but no doubt there are others. The `1*`'s convert each boolean array into an array of 1's and 0's (it is my preferred alternative to the double negative used in the original formula to do the same conversion job). The two arrays are multiplied together on a corresponding element basis giving a "product array" of length 94 which also comprises 1's and 0's. This array is then converted back to an array of `True` and `False` elements via the `1=` bit. The resulting boolean array has 94 elements and, because of the way it is constructed, its elements have the required properties. (Readers of a mathematical mind will recognise the isomorphism being exploited here to get round Excel's behaviour with `AND` in array formulae.)

Substituting the above for the first argument of the `IF()` function in the original formula should do the trick.

One final observation: very long formulae can be simplified using Excel's Name Manager. It is perfectly valid to use a formula when defining a name, so `PhoneIndex` can be defined in the Name Manager as set out above. Names can also utilise other names in their definition, so providing easy means of defining `PhoneIndex2` and `CallCount`. Ultimately, the phone calls formula could be written much more succinctly as `=SUM(--(CallCount>0))`. Sensible use of naming can be used to show how a complex formula has been constructed from individual elements and can greatly ease the burden of understanding what the formula is intended to do - useful when, as in this case, the formula requires change.